# Why does GAE ignore my yaml command to require admin login?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication

I am developing a GAE application.  Using the localhost for development is a nuisance because there are some interacting components that require the system to be on the internet.  However, I feel weird about having a pre-release version of the app live so I am enable it when I'm troubleshooting it and then disable it.  It would be better to require admin login so I can have it online and keep it private.  When I make the (very simple) necessary changes to app.yaml and update the app, nothing changes.  I can still access it without being logged in (I checked that I was logged out of google).  Any ideas?  My app.yaml text is below.  Incidentally, the only other handler that requires a login, remote_api, is also misbehaving.  It returns the error 'This request did not contain a necessary header'.

```
application: (removed for privacy)
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /remote_api
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py
  login: admin

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /javascript
  static_dir: javascript

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /.*
  script: example.py
  login: admin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that you weren't actually logged out. This can happen because there's a delay when you use the logout feature on other Google apps -- to avoid having to check back with the Google Account service for every request, App Engine uses a short-lived cookie that allows access regardless of what the Google Accounts service things until it times out (I think it's 5 minutes).

If you really want to check whether you can access this while logged out, use Chrome's Incognito Window.  (Or wait 5 minutes. :-)

The remote_api behavior can also be explained: for security reasons (to thwart certain Javascript-based attacks) the remote_api handler doesn't let web browsers access the handler.  It only accepts requests from the dedicated remote_api client library, which passes an extra header that Javascript code cannot set.

By the way, it's probably better to use the standard remote_api handler location and use the builtins clause to enable it:

```
builtins:
- remote_api: on
```